# Assistance required to connect to Foursquare via TIBCO BW using REST / JSON API - 1.1

Tags: json, rest, foursquare, tibco

We have an assignment to check the compatibility of Quick connect project for Foursquare against the REST/JSON 1.1.

When I am testing the process, while invoking Rest API for query Check-in, the process is throwing an error – “OAuth token invalid or revoked”. Can you kindly help to fix this issue.

Access_token for this was generated by registering a sample app with Foursuare.com, having www.google.com as welcome page and redirect URL. Please let me know if this is causing the issue.

Also, let me know is there is any standard method to generate the access_token for this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Shree.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not following Foursquare's [instructions on connecting](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) properly, or need to reconnect to get a new `access_token`. Keep in mind that the `access_token` isn't the `code` that comes back in the redirect, the `code` needs to be used to exchange for the `access_token`.